# GWT + Eclipse + external JAR files

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, jar

I am using the latest Eclipse with the latest GWT and GWT plugins.

I need to use external JAR files from the servlet serving the gwt client. Where is the correct place for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your server-side code can access jars in `/war/WEB-INF/lib`.  Just drop them in!

Answer (score 1):

What about `GWTProject/war/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-servlet.jar` ?

Answer (score 0):

Put them under WEB-INF/lib. ALSO you need to add them to the classpath settings under Eclipse.